# Is this type of logical condition check bad practice?

Tags: c#, logical-operators

I've got a method that returns a result class. The result class has a Boolean property to indicate if an operation was successful or not. It can only ever be true if a number of criteria are true. I thought that the following code would be more concise than the equivalent if statement but I wanted to check if what I'm doing is regarded as bad practice or not.

```
bool successfullyParsed;

bool conditionA = true;
bool conditionB = true;

successfullyParsed = conditionA && conditionB;
//successfullyParsed should only be true if both criteria are true.
```

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not bad practice - in fact it can be a great way to make more complex conditional logic more readable, for instance (a trivial example):

```
bool isLive = pages.Any(x => x.Live == true && x.Published == true && ...)
```

In your example could you not just do the following to make it even more readable?

```
bool conditionA = true;
bool conditionB = true;

bool successfullyParsed = conditionA && conditionB;
```

This way you can remove the initial declaration of `successfullyParsed`.

If your method were to return your successfully parsed boolean then you could shorten it even further to:

```
bool conditionA = true;
bool conditionB = true;

return conditionA && conditionB;
```

Comment: Unless you optimization is of the utmost importance, this is the perfect answer. Remember, you don't code for yourself. You code for the next poor schlub (even if that's you) that looks at the code. This logic will make the next guys time much easier.

Answer (score 1):

That's perfectly fine, and in fact an elegant solution to the problem.